# How to get Selenium and TestNG to open one browser to run tests in multiple classes

Tags: selenium, testng

I am using Selenium with TestNG to test a website. I have created tests using the Selenium IDE and exported them to TestNG with each test being a method in a class. Eg,

For login tests there is a Login class which has methods testLogin(), testLogin2() etc
For signup tests there is a Signup class has methods testSignup(), testSignup2(), etc

I am using Ant to run the tests which works fine except that each class will open up a browser and then run its methods, eg, if I have five classes, then five browsers will open simultaneously and then run the tests.

What I want is to get Ant/Selenium/TestNG to just open up one browser and then run all the tests (in the same browser) in all the classes that I have specified in testng.xml. Using the example above, I want one browser to open then run testLogin(), testLogin2(), testSignup(), testSignup2().
If this cannot be achieved, then I want to open a browser, run all tests in a class then close the browser then open another browser then run the set of test methods in the next class.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Today I have found the answer that works for me. Give me a few minutes to gather all code samples :)

Init.java

```
//base class that will be called before all tests
@Test(groups = "init")
public class Init{

    DefaultSelenium browser;

    public void start(ITestContext itc){
        browser = (DefaultSelenium) itc.getAttribute("browser");
        browser.open("url");
        browser.click("xpath");
    }

}
```

TemplateForClasses.java

```
/* - all public methods will be tests
 * - all tests will be called after group init
 * - just before suite will start we will start 1 browser instance
 */
@Test(dependsOnGroup="init")
public class TemplateForClasses{

    DefaultSelenium browser;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void startBrowser(ITestContext itc){
        browser = new DefaultSelenium(host,port,browser_type,url);
        itc.setAttribute("browser",browser);
        browser.start();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void stopBrowser(ITestContext itc){
        browser = (DefaultSelenium) itc.getAttribute("browser");
        browser.stop();
    }

    //any other: @Before, @After methods

}
```

FirstGroupOfTests.java

```
//all tests classes will inherit preferences set in TemplateForClasses
public class FirstGroupOfTests extends TemplateForClasses{

    public void FirstTest(ITestContext itc){
        browser = (DefaultSelenium) itc.getAttribute("browser");
        //browser.click("start");
    }

}
```

idea:

- start browser just once have tests
- that run before every other tests(isBrowserRunning)
- refer to browser from single test

This code was tested but currently I took it from the top of my head so possibly I will edit it tomorrow to make it more exact.

Update:
This result is based on testng.org documentation + some questions asked by me on stackoverflow + some answers found on several forums/groups

I must add I'm running testng programatically and I'm generating xml on the fly (as it is done on documentation.org). I am using it all in one package, I added package to the xml, included only classes Init + the ones that inherit from TemplateForClasses. If you need that xml, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I too was stuck in the same problem for quite some time. I'll explain it in the simplest terms possible. Consider the following example:

```
Class A (contains the code selenium.start();)
|
|(inherited classes)
|--------class B   }
|--------class C   }  Have some @Test methods
|--------class D   }
```

Now everytime we run these test methods it will execute the code in the parent class constructor selenium.start(); Thats when the multiple browsers will all open up on your screen.

Now one by one the test methods will get executed - suppose tests in class B are executed they will be happening in one window, for class C another and so on.

So basically, all you have to do is remove the start() code from the parent constructor and put it somewhere in the classes B, C and D.

As long as you keep working with one selenium object everything will happen in one browser window. When you put start(); that browser will open (if it wasnt open) and a new session is created. stop(); and the session is terminated.

The flow of control goes like this=>

```
Class A, Class B
Class A, Class C
Class A, Class D
```

So if you can figure out a way to keep using the same selenium object with only 1 start() and 1 stop() for the entire execution sequence shown above, your test execution will happen in only one browser window.

If you put start() code in class A and stop code in each of B,C and D then you will have 3 windows open and one by one they will close as execution progresses.

If you put start() and stop() code individually in B,C and D then you will see one browser opening, executing test cases, closing. Another will then open, execute test cases for C, close etc.

Hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I did this with Spring's dependency injection. And the init code is in a factory. I needed a way to have a Selenium instance shared not only between tests but between helper classes. Very seldom is selenium.someMethod() called directly in the tests. It more like helper.goToSomePage() or preferencesPage.changePassword(....).

It could be considered a bad idea to have a Selenium instance shared between tests, but the few bugs it brought were not that hard to find. The tests are run sequentially and the Selenium object need not be thread-safe. The state of the object must be kept consistent though.

For info, Spring is a Java framework and Dependency injection is only a part of it. Other DI frameworks like Guice can of course be used instead.